# How do I load a custom stylesheet based on the selection on a splash page?

Tags: php, css, themes, customization

When my visitors arrive at my site, they'll be greeted by a splash page with a sort of "theme selection." When they select the theme, they'll be redirected to the actual site, which would load the appropriate external stylesheet based on their selection. To do so, I'd like to avoid using radio buttons; instead, just a clickable link.

Answer (score 2):

on clicked link send a flag concatenated with URL and on the landing page select the stylesheet according to the flag recieved. and if needed later, save it in session or coockies for latter calls as well.